# iOS/Android - Access Firebase Database from Another App

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

> There are two apps in my firebase project (Customer and Driver apps).

**Case:**   In Firebase Database, I am saving from Customer app basic order lists such as `"NameOfCustomer"`, `"Telephone"`, `"ProductType"`, `"DeliveryPlace"`, "`TimeOfDelivery`".

**Problem:** I am unable to retrieve those order lists in Driver app.

**Note:** I undertand, when creating own Database in backend, I used to parse API from one app to another. But, Firebase is cloud based, and it is a key-value database. Therefore, I am in dilemma as how to connect two apps together to share data.

**Firebase Solution:** Read the documentation and other stackoverflow posts, found a piece of code:

```
    // Manually configure Firebase Options
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setApplicationId("1:27992087142:android:ce3b6448250083d1") // Required for Analytics.
        .setApiKey("AIzaSyADUe90ULnQDuGShD9W23RDP0xmeDc6Mvw") // Required for Auth.
        .setDatabaseUrl("https://myproject.firebaseio.com") // Required for RTDB.
        .build();
```

It seems not to work!

**P.S.** I have only Phone Authentication. And sharing data in Customer app itself working, when tested.

Anyone who had developed such multiple apps before, figure this out please.

Comment: You're saying you have iOSA and AndroidA in Firebase connected and you want iOSB and AndroidB to also access that database?

Comment: Imagine: I have iOSA and AndroidA. when saved to database from iOSA or AndroidA that data should be retrieved from iOSB or AndroidB

Comment: Both iOS and Android projects are in one firebase console project

Comment: Did you add all apps into the Firebase console? Located on the Overview?

Comment: Is this what you're trying to accomplish: https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/ - I don't wanna post an answer until I am certain your expected result :)

Comment: yes I tried this out, even posted above piece of code. but it didnt work. I think, there should be another magic to do to it

Comment: What doesn't work? The piece of code you shared just sets up some configuration. It doesn't read nor share any data yet. What code is failing? What's the problem you see?

Comment: Add All 4 Apps in single Project with different Bundle ids, all those apps will access same database and same storage.